# passing parameter from a html page inside a gwt frame to a different frame in the same gwt app

Tags: html, gwt, parameters, frame

I have 2 different GWT frames inside the same GWT app. The first frame contains a HTML page with url links. How can I open the clicked links to the 2nd frame?

Answer (score 0):

Create those 'url links' in the first one as GWT `Anchor`s and add a click handler which does whatever you want it to do in the second frame.